# How can I replace() multiple characters at once?

Tags: javascript, replace

I have an string like this:

```
var set = 'ñ This is a Test Ñ';
```

What I need to do is replace `ñ` and `Ñ` with `n`. I tried:

```
set.replace(/\u00F1/g, 'n');
```

but it only replaces the `ñ`.

Comment: The variable Set is obtained from a input Value, I know u00F1 = ñ And u00D1 = Ñ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a cleaner way to write this, but this should work. The `|` acts as an `OR` in regex.

```
a = set.replace(/\u00F1|\u00D1/g, 'n');
```